# Search range of folders

Tags: c#, range, directory

I have to search on a lot of folders. I have a network directory structure like this:

```
    \\share\folder0000
    \\share\folder1000
    \\share\folder2000
    \\share\folder3000
```

Inside each folder I have something like this:

```
    \\share\folder1000\1000
    \\share\folder1000\1001
    \\share\folder1000\1002
    \\share\folder1000\1003
```

I need to find a lot of files but intead of search all folders I want to search a range of folders, because it will be faster. It might be a good idea to look at a range of folders like:
    Search from "\share\folder1000\1000 to \share\folder1000\1100", without to write all dirs.

Any suggestion? Thank you. The code I have is the following:

```
var diretorios = new List<string>() { @"\\share\folder1000\1000" };
// What extensions that we want to search
var extensoes = new List<string>() { "*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.tiff", "*.gif" };
// This 2 foreach are to search for the files with the extension that is on the extensoes and on all directories that are on diretorios
// In for foreach we go through all the extensions that we want to search
foreach (string entryExtensions in extensoes)
{
// Now we must go through all the directories to search for the extension that is on the entryExtensions
foreach (string entryDirectory in diretorios)
{
// SearchOption.AllDirectories search the directory and sub directorys if necessary
filesList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(entryDirectory, entryExtensions, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
}
// And now here we will add all the files that it has found into the DataTable
foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
{
```

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/format

Comment: I can't see your tries.

Comment: Use the editor and the code-format button after you have selected the code snippet. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I recently arrived here on the SO platform and I have some difficulty understanding the operation. You do not miss an opportunity to lower my reputation. In this way certainly will not have many employees who decided to start programming and chose this platform as the place where they can ask questions.

Comment: I agree, the down votes are an irritation. They are usually not the people who comment sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var extensoes = new List<string>() { "*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.tiff", "*.gif" };
foreach(var folderNumber in Enumerable.Range(1000, 11).ToList())
{
    var folderToSearch = $@"\\share\folder1000\{folderNumber}";
}
```

This gives all folders between 1000 and 1011.

UPDATED

Using `SearchOption.AllDirectories` all you need is the list of root/base folders. This then gives you a list of all the files in all subfolders which are then filtered by extension. `EnumerateFiles` is more efficient than `GetFiles`for large collections.

```
var extensoes = new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".bmp", ".png", ".tiff", ".gif" };
//  set up list of root folders
foreach (var folderNumber in Enumerable.Range(1000, 11).ToList())
{
    var folderToSearch = $@"\\share\folder{folderNumber}";
    List<string> fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                                   folderToSearch, "*.*",
                                   SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                      .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
                                      .Where(x => extensoes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x)))
                                      .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(fileList.Count());
    foreach (var fileName in fileList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have another "AddRange". `var diretorios = new List<string>() { @"\\share\folder1000\1000" };
var extensoes = new List<string>() { "*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.tiff", "*.gif" };
foreach (string entryExtensions in extensoes)
{
{
filesList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(entryDirectory, entryExtensions, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
}
foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
{`

Comment: You can then use a Lambda expression to find extension in list rather than iterate through the extensions

Comment: can you take a look to my code on first post to try to understand what i am saying? Thank you.

Comment: Happy to but can't until tomorrow. Okay?

Comment: I've updated my answer to a 'full' solution rather than basing it on yours as the approach to folders and extensions is too different.